# Upgrade of Webpack 1 to 4 got so complicated

Tags: node.js, webpack, upgrade, webpack-4

I have been stuck with this upgrade since 2 days and I have made some progress.
It is an old project and I have to take it a bit forward.

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
//const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  public: path.join(__dirname, 'src/public'),
  assets: path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
  styles: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/bootstrap-grid-rtl.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/main.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/PrintStyle.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/react-datepicker.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/css/tracker.css'),

  ]
};

const isDebug = !process.argv.includes('--release');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: false,
          ecma: 6,
          mangle: true
        },
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ], 
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendor',
              chunks: 'all'
          }
      }
  }
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill',PATHS.app],
    style: PATHS.styles
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, PATHS.app),
        ],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: isDebug,
          babelrc: true,
          presets: ['latest', 'react',
            ...isDebug ? [] : [
              'react-optimize',
            ],
          ],
          plugins: [
            'transform-object-rest-spread',
            'transform-object-assign',
            [
              'react-intl', {
                'messagesDir': './build/messages',
                'enforceDescriptions': false
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: 
          {
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              'style-loader',
              `css-loader?${JSON.stringify({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: isDebug ? '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:5]',
                discardComments: { removeAll: true },
              })}`,
              'resolve-url-loader',
              'postcss-loader?pack=default'
            )
          }
        ,
        exclude: PATHS.styles,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
          loader:
            ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              'style-loader',
              `css-loader?${JSON.stringify({
                localIdentName: isDebug ? '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:5]',
                minimize: true,
                discardComments: { removeAll: true },
              })}`,
              'resolve-url-loader'
            )
          }
        ],
        exclude: PATHS.app,
        include: PATHS.styles
      },
      {
        test: /\.sss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'json-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader:
              `file-loader?${JSON.stringify({
                name: isDebug ? '/[path][name].[ext]?[hash:8]' : '/fonts/[hash:8].[ext]',
              })}`
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader:
              `file-loader?${JSON.stringify({
                name: isDebug ? '/[path][name].[ext]?[hash:8]' : '/images/[hash:8].[ext]'
              })}`
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDebug ? '"development"' : '"production"',
      'process.env.BROWSER': true,
      __DEV__: isDebug,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css', {allChunks: true}),

    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: {removeAll: true } },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'GACA Portal',
      template: path.join(PATHS.public, 'index.ejs'),
      favicon:  path.join(PATHS.assets, 'images/favicon.ico'),
    }),

    ...isDebug? [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
        multiStep: true
      }),

    ] : [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(PATHS.build, {
        root: process.cwd()
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()

  ] //else ends
],

// Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
bail: !isDebug,
cache: false,

stats: {
  colors: true,
  reasons: isDebug,
  timings: true,
},

devtool: isDebug ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : false,
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  stats: 'errors-only',
  port: 3000,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  publicPath: '/',
  contentBase: PATHS.build,
  proxy: {
    '/api/**': {
      target: 'http://localhost:8080',
      secure: false
    }
  }
},

/*postcss: [
  require('postcss-partial-import')(),
  require('postcss-url')(),
  require('postcss-custom-properties')(),
  require('postcss-custom-media')(),
  require('postcss-media-minmax')(),
  require('postcss-custom-selectors')(),
  require('autoprefixer')({
    browsers: [
      '>1%',
      'last 4 versions',
      'Firefox ESR',
      'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
    ],
  })
]*/

};
```

Now I am trying to `npm start` but I still getting this error:

```
× ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].use should be one of these:
   non-empty string | function | object { ident?, loader?, options?, query? } | function | [non-empty string | function | object { ident?, loader?, options?, query? }]
   -> Modifiers applied to the module when rule is matched
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[1].use should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[1].use should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[1].use.loader should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[1].use should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[1].use should be an array:
      [non-empty string | function | object { ident?, loader?, options?, query? }]
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use should be an object.
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use[0] should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use[0] should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[2].use[0].loader should be a string.
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
```

Any help would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide from Webpack.
https://webpack.js.org/migrate/

If you have plugin which is not provided by webpack, please go and check on the repo.

Comment: I went through those step but in vain, my webpack configuration file is so complicated. So I removed webpack and replaced it with CRA

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first upgrading to version 2 or 3 https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/ , you will have clear documentation and you will find great help in Google ...

And only then continue to version 4 https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4/

Answer (score 0):

I just left it away and create a new project with **create app cli** and copied the content and formatted the structure